# Вывести строку в столбик, выранивание по правому краю JavaScript

Tags: javascript, строки, функции, split

Выведите строку по одному слову в столбик, выравнивание по правому краю.
Функция получает строку из нескольких слов. Выведите слова в столбик, выравнивание по правому краю.
Например,

```
text = 'I will get everything I want'.
```

Напишите функцию с именем `wordsInColumn`, которая принимает строку `text` в качестве аргумента и возвращает строку, разделенную на слова, которые выводятся по одному в строке с выравниванием по правому краю.

Пример:

функция

```
wordsInColumn("Enjoy every moment"):

function wordsInColumn(text){

}
```

Пожалуйста, помогите с решением, не знаю с чего начать.В решении нужно использрвать методы `split` и `repeat`? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log(wordsInColumn("I will get everything I want"));

function wordsInColumn(text) {
  let words = text.split(' ');
  let maxLength = Math.max.apply(null, words.map(w => w.length));
  return words.map(w => ' '.repeat(maxLength - w.length) + w).join('\n');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А есть ли способ, чтобы вывести это строкой, не массивом, и каждое слово в строке по правому краю в столбик?

Comment: @MaryK Eсть способ.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @MaryK Пожалуйста. Про "галочку" Вы знаете.